# Jquery making "content" based on h1 h2 h3 tags

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add a content before some div which has several sections and sub sections.

Can I parse it on fly using jquery?

For example I would like to have some thing like:

```
<div id="cont"></div>
<div id="help-area">
<h1>Head1</h1>
   ...
   ...
 <h3>Subsection1</h3>
    ....
    ....
</div>
```

As an output I would like to have:

```
<div id="cont">
 <ul>
  <li>Head1
     <ul>
       <li>Subsection1</li>
     </ul> 
  </li>
  ....
 </ul>
</div>
<div id="help-area">
<h1>Head1</h1>
   ...
   ...
 <h3>Subsection1</h3>
    ....
    ....
</div>
```

Can I achieve it using jquery or I should parse it by PHP?

Thanks in advance.
Arman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do it with jQuery, but of course that would mean that anyone accessing the page without JavaScript enabled wouldn't have access to the table of contents. Not ideal.

But something along these lines:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var ul = null;
  var lasth1 = null;
  var lasth1ul = null;
  var lasth2 = null;
  var lasth2ul = null;

  $("h1, h2, h3").each(function() {

    switch (this.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
      case "h1":
        if (!ul) {
          ul = $("<ul>");
        }
        lasth1 = $("<li>").html($(this).html()).appendTo(ul);
        lasth1ul = null;
        lasth2ul = null;
        break;
      case "h2":
        if (!lasth1) {
          // Deal with invalid condition, h2 with no h1 before it
        }
        else {
          if (!lasth1ul) {
            lasth1ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(lasth1);
          }
          lasth2 = $("<li>").html($(this).html()).appendTo(lasth1ul);
        }
        break;
      case "h3":
        if (!lasth2) {
          // Deal with invalid condition, h3 with no h2 before it
        }
        else {
          if (!lasth2ul) {
            lasth2ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(lasth2);
          }
          $("<li>").html($(this).html()).appendTo(lasth2ul);
        }
        break;
    }

  });
  if (ul) {
    $("#cont").append(ul);
  }

});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uvihoy/1/)

Note that jQuery guarantees that you'll receive the matched elements in document order.

The above is just one way to do it. You could also use a recursive descent approach, but for just three levels the above is simple and doesn't repeat itself *that* much...

Comment: Thank you simple and quick solution. Usually I prefer little bit repeating of things, rather than a complex code which is after a year unreadable.

Comment: @Arman: I think they're unicorns. :-) Good deal, glad that helped.

Comment: Are they new in the stack city? I haven't  seen them before:)

Comment: @Arman: Today is **[April 1st](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_fool%27s_day)**. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can. If you access to to content you want to show then all you do is use the "append" and "prepend" functions of jQuery. As a quick demo, check this

```
$("#cont").append("<ul><li>Head1<ul><li>Subsection1</li></ul></li></ul>")
```

Comment: @Nikhill: Thanks, How can I get all h1-h2-h3 recursively?

Comment: You need to explicitly code for each of them. There is no quick way of doing this (as far as I know!)